# How to use link to Viber in Wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress, jetpack, viber

I need to put link to chat in Viber on this site. This link looks like this:

```
<a href='viber://chat?number=ххххххххх' target='_blank'>Link</a>
```

But it doesn't work! If I use code above on site, eventually it gives this link:

```
<a href='//chat?number=ххххххххх' target='_blank'>Link</a>
```

I can guess, wordpress (or maybe plugin JetPack, I don't know) deletes unfamiliar protocols (but leave protocols like https, http).

So my question - what is the problem and how can I fix it without javascript (js forbidden :( )?

Comment: Are you used esc_url() function to display the link?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use javascript here.

Answer (score 3):

In your theme functions.php (preferable child theme) add this to allow viber protocol.

```
add_filter( 'kses_allowed_protocols', function ( $protocols ) {
   $protocols[] = 'viber';
   return $protocols;
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using wp_kses_post to display link but 'viber:' is not in the list of allowed protocols. To fix it you just have to add 'viber:' to allowed protocols list or use a different way to display content.